# How to configure MongooseIM MUC Light to work with multiple owner?

Tags: erlang, xmpp, chat, xmppframework, mongoose-im

I'm doing a chatting apps that require group chat to have multiple owner, so that they can add user to the room. According to mongoose muclight documentation, it only allows one owner in a muc light room. Is there any other way to do that? Is there any extension i can use to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official MUC Light documentation it's possible to allow any room member to add new users to a room (from http://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/open-extensions/muc_light/ section *2. Requirements*, emphasis mine):

> 2. Users cannot join rooms on their own. They have to be added by the room owner or **(if configured by service administrator) any other occupant.**

Later in the same document section *5.4 Changing the occupant list* describes how to add/invite users to a room.

The configuration option required to allow any member to add users to a room is called `all_can_invite` and, among other options, is described at http://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/mod_muc_light.

Comment: Hi erszcz, do they allow to remove user as well after they have added new member? it's like whatsapp, multiple admin role in a group chat

Comment: @erszcz : how we can figure out many admins are there on one group ?

Comment: The "service administrator" in the context of the above quoted text is the operator of the server, where MongooseIM is installed. It's not a user with the "admin" role in the group chat. There is no "admin" role in MUC Light. The same doc says: _There MUST be at most one owner in the room (the service can choose to treat all users equally)_. Simply, if the `all_can_invite` option is set, any user can add other users to a room.

Comment: I wouldn't mind an upvote if you consider this info helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

They don't allow removing users from the room with the following config for mod_muc_light

```
{equal_occupants, true},{all_can_configure, true},{all_can_invite, true}
```

only invite new users, which is a bit counterintuitive but not against the docs.